# How to show the list of workitems retrieved from (queryByWiql) in query tab without creating a query

Tags: typescript, azure-devops

```
 var query = {
            query: "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItem WHERE [System.State] NOT IN ('Closed','Completed','Resolved','Removed', 'Done')"
        };

        let workitems: any[];
        let idstring: string = "";

        client.queryByWiql(query, VSS.getWebContext().project.id).then((wi) =>
        {
            workitems = wi.workItems;


            for (let workitemid of workitems)
            {
                idstring = idstring + workitemid["id"] + ","; 
            }

        },
                    (createquery) => {

                    });





    }
```

idstring has list of workitems. this work-items I have to open in query tab , I don't want to create a new query

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the result in Query tab as the query result?

Comment: yes ... i want to show in query tab as a result. but dont want to create a new query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can’t display the result in query tab through extension, you can display the result in [hub extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/extend-analytics/building-extension-against-analytics-service) in Work tab.